# Activiti and PostgreSQL

Tags: spring, postgresql, activiti

I try to start my project context with `org.activiti.spring.SpringProcessEngineConfiguration` bean. I defined it in two datasources, the first was with url oriented to H2 and activiti was creating own tables, and the second was with url oriented to Postgres and activiti somehow wasn't creating own tables. 
May be somebody met this problem?

Two my datasources:

```
<bean class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
          destroy-method="close" id="dataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="net.sf.log4jdbc.DriverSpy" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/mem:base-test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;MVCC=true" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="root" />
        <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true" />
        <property name="testOnReturn" value="true" />
        <property name="testWhileIdle" value="true" />
        <property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="1800000" />
        <property name="numTestsPerEvictionRun" value="3" />
        <property name="minEvictableIdleTimeMillis" value="1800000" />
        <property name="defaultAutoCommit" value="true" />
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
          destroy-method="close" id="dataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="net.sf.log4jdbc.DriverSpy"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/base-test2"/>
        <property name="username" value="root"/>
        <property name="password" value="root"/>
        <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true"/>
        <property name="testOnReturn" value="true"/>
        <property name="testWhileIdle" value="true"/>
        <property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="1800000"/>
        <property name="numTestsPerEvictionRun" value="3"/>
        <property name="minEvictableIdleTimeMillis" value="1800000"/>
        <property name="defaultAutoCommit" value="true"/>
    </bean>
```

And my SpringProcessEngineConfiguration

```
<bean id="processEngineConfiguration" class="org.activiti.spring.SpringProcessEngineConfiguration">
        <property name="databaseType" value="postgres" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
        <property name="databaseSchemaUpdate" value="true" />
        <property name="jpaEntityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
        <property name="jpaHandleTransaction" value="true" />
        <property name="jpaCloseEntityManager" value="true" />
        <property name="deploymentResources" value="classpath:**/*.bpmn20.xml" />
        <property name="formTypes" ref="customFormTypes" />
        <property name="history" value="activity" />
        <property name="jobExecutorActivate" value="true" />
    </bean>
```

Comment: Any errors in the log file? Maybe try with the **real** Postgres driver first before using the wrapper log4jdbc is really old, don't know if it properly works with a current JDBC4 driver

Comment: Or maybe problem with privileges in postgreSQL